# How to access Lotus Notes document 'hidden' in categorized view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Lotus Notes database on a Domino server.  The docs in the database use roles in reader and author fields.  Replication conflicts are to be merged.

I can see some docs in a categorized view, but I cannot seem to get to them:

[image: Lotus Notes view with expanded category hiding docs]

While the category shows that there are 8 docs under the category, the docs do not show up.  I have removed the 'show responses in a hierarchy' from the view design, so replication conflicts should appear (shouldn't they?).

If this was due to reader fields, I should be able to see the docs as I am using the server administrator ID in the group of admins given Full Server Access in the Server document.

I have run fixup on docs and views.  Is it possible that the docs have become encrypted somehow?  The users don't really know how to do this...

As a full access server admin, how can I find these hidden docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being in the group with Full Access Admin rights on a specific server is only the first step. Next you need to use the IBM Domino Administration client to turn on Full Access Administration. It will remain on only as long as you allow it OR the IBM Domino Administration client closes.

Comment: In my experience, it may be necessary to shut down the regular client and designer client, then use the Domino Admin client to turn on Full Access, then restart the other clients, otherwise you still might not see the docments hdden by reader fields.

Comment: I did not know that enabling Full Access Administration was a separate step.  That should open up everything whether in reader fields or not.  I believe the problem is due to merging replication conflicts with no conflict doc (it is one of the Form options).  This will cause replication conflicts to be merged as best as possible and deleting what would be a replication document otherwise.  These deleted rep conflicts are still floating around and are only visible in a categorized view -- that is, only the category field value, the doc does not appear.  I will follow up later with results.  Thx

Comment: The hidden docs were due to unpopulated Reader fields.  I was able to find them once I enabled Full Access Administration from the Domino Administrator client.  I did not have to close the Notes client, just the db I needed to access with full access administrator rights.  Thanks again.